# I can not enter anything in jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

[The jquery ui autocomplete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

```
var availableTags = [
         "Ruby",
         "Scala",
         "Scheme"
        ];

        $("#SearchBox").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags

        });
```

Thats the resulting html:

```
<div id="SearchBox" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off"></div>
```

When I debug the plugin initialization the first time the site is loaded I can see my 3 items in the SearchBox, but I can NOT edit or enter anything.

Why is that?

I am using JQuery UI 1.10 and JQuery 1.9.0

Comment: You're attempting to attach autocomplete to a `div`? What do you expect to happen? You'll need to use an `input`/`textarea` or make the `div` contentEditable.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Well I thought there is a common/consistent way of using jquery plugins. I have used now several and always I had to init ialize them with a div and its id. Why can the autocomplete not render an editable input inside this div? Thats was my assumption. Thank you Andrew now it works :)